# How to add to a user-user correlations table based on whether users have rated any of the same items?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building a site that determines correlation values between users based on users liking or disliking posts on the site. To do so, I'm setting up my database with a lot of materialized views (tables updated with SQL triggers upon the alteration of other tables).

One of the tables I would like to update is a table storing information about the relationship between users, based on a table storing the rates (likes and dislikes on posts) users have provided.

In the `rates` table I have the columns `user_id`, `post_id`, and `liked` (1 if the user liked the post, -1 if the user disliked the post.)

In the table of user-user correlations, I plan on having the columns `user_id_a`, `user_id_b`, `agreed`, `disagreed`, and `total`. Where `agreed` is the number of posts they rated the same,  `disagreed` is the number of posts they rated opposite, and `total` is the total number of posts they have both rated.

I want to set up a trigger on the `rates` table so that when a row is added to it, it will:

- Add all necessary user-user correlation rows that didn't already exist to the user-user correlations table
- Update the `agreed`, `disageed`, and `total` columns in all relevant rows of the user-user correlation tables

EDIT: my question is how to write the queries listed in the bullet points. I know how to write triggers, I just can't figure out how to make he queries that go inside of them in this case.

I also will need to write similar triggers for when rows in `rates` are updated or deleted.

I'm working in a MySQL database.

Comment: What is your question?  And, how many users and posts do you have?  Are separate tables really necessary?

Comment: What is the problem? Do you want guidance on the basics of writing triggers? If you know how to write triggers, what is it about this problem that is causing you difficulty? Perhaps you'd like some comments on whether your proposed approach is reasonable? If so, we may need further information such as how many users (now and rate of growth)? How frequently are ratings made? How frequently would your proposed "correlations" table be accessed? etc.

Comment: My question is how to write the queries listed in the bullet points. I know how to make triggers. I'll edit my question.